# R check if date is 2 years apart

Tags: r, date

I have a dataset with two columns Id and Date as shown below using a toy dataset.

```
   Id         Date
   5373283    2010-11-05
   5373283    2014-11-05
   5373283    2001-07-13
   5373283    2007-12-01
   5373283    2015-07-07 
   3475684    2015-05-19
   3475684    2010-06-24
```

I want to check if any of the dates for `each id` are within 2 years range. If they are then a column will show yes, if not, No. The final output would look like this

```
   Id         Status
   5373283    Yes
   3475684    No
```

`Yes` for `Id 5373283` because the two dates `2014-11-05` and `2015-07-07` are within two years of each other. `No` for `Id 3475684` because the two dates are more than 2 years apart. Any help on accomplishing this much appreciated.

Comment: `Id=5373283` has other observations.  How do you want to treat them?

Comment: @KotaMori ignore any other dates if they are not 2 years apart :). Only looking to see if any date combination is within 2 years of each other for that ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hypothetical data.

```
DF <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2),
                 date = c("2010-10-9", "2012-10-8", "2008-10-5",
                          "2007-7-5", "2009-7-5"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

The code below gets the minimal interval by ID in days.
What is happening is: 
`mutate` redefines the date as `Date` class
`arrange` sort the data by date
`group_by` tells the following computation shall be done for each ID,
`summarize` computes the minimum difference.

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(diffmin = as.numeric(min(diff(date)), units = "days"))
#     id diffmin
#  (dbl)   (dbl)
#1     1     730
#2     2     731
```

If you can ignore leap years, this being smaller than or equal to 730 means within 2 years.  Note that difference between `2007-7-5` and `2009-7-5` is 731 days, and thus judged as out of 2 years.

If this is not good to you, simple days-difference is not enough. I would need to define a custom checker function.

```
check2years <- function(a, b) {
  # check if b - a <= 2 years
  # assumes a and b are Date
  yr_a <- format(a, "%Y") %>% as.integer()
  yr_b <- format(b, "%Y") %>% as.integer()
  dy_a <- format(a, "%m-%d")
  dy_b <- format(b, "%m-%d")
  (yr_b - yr_a < 2) | ((yr_b - yr_a == 2) & (dy_b >= dy_a))
}
```

Then, you can check if any combination is within 2 years by the following.

```
DF %>% mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(within2yr = any(check2years(head(date, length(date)-1), 
                                        tail(date, length(date)-1))))
#     id within2yr
#  (dbl)     (lgl)
#1     1      TRUE
#2     2      TRUE
```

Comment: that worked great, if there were two same dates then the results turned to Infinity. This is trivial issue in my case but just suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You can also solve this without any library:

Using your example:

```
Id = c(5373283,5373283,5373283,5373283,5373283,3475684,3475684)
Date = as.Date(c("2010-11-05","2014-11-05","2001-07-13","2007-12-01","2015-07-07","2015-05-19","2010-06-24"))
df = data.frame(Id,Date)

> df
       Id       Date
7 3475684 2010-06-24
6 3475684 2015-05-19
3 5373283 2001-07-13
4 5373283 2007-12-01
1 5373283 2010-11-05
2 5373283 2014-11-05
5 5373283 2015-07-07
```

**Do the following:**

First order your data first by Id then by Date

```
df = df[order(df$Id,df$Date),]
```

Do an `aggregate` by Id using the function `min(diff(x))`, where x are the dates for each Id.

```
z = aggregate(df$Date,by = list(Id = df$Id),FUN = function(x){min(diff(x))})
```

What this function does is it returns the lowest difference between adjacent dates. This is why you need to order the data frame first.
This returns:

```
> z
       Id     x
1 3475684 1790 
2 5373283  244
```

Where column `x` is the minimum difference in days.

Here, you only need to evaluate is if column `x` is less than or equal to 2*365

```
z$result  = z$x<=2*365
```

Giving:

```
       Id     x result
1 3475684 1790   FALSE
2 5373283  244    TRUE
```

**Final code**

```
df = df[order(df$Id,df$Date),]
z = aggregate(df$Date,by = list(Id = df$Id),FUN = function(x){min(diff(x))})
z$result  = z$x>=2*365
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this with library `dplyr` with the idea of taking top two dates in sorted order for each ID and see if they differ by two years:

```
library(dplyr)
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date)
df %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  summarise(Status = as.numeric(difftime(max(Date), Date[order(Date, decreasing = TRUE)][2], units = 'days')) < 730)
```

Output will be as follows:

```
Source: local data frame [2 x 2]

       Id Status
    (int)  (lgl)
1 3475684  FALSE
2 5373283   TRUE
```